# Boostrap 3 : alignment problems of an input control inside nested "row" div class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Boostrap 3. Is it normal that an input control inside a DIV with "row" class is not aligned left with the parent ? 
It is shifted on the left. I think it might be a bug ?

Is there a way to make it aligned properly without tweaking CSS (meaning through Bootsrap-only CSS classes).

Please find the demonstration of the problem here :
http://jsfiddle.net/7vRQr/2/

```
<div class="col-xs-11">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
        <h2 class="main-info-title">Following input should be aligned</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" class="col-xs-12" placeholder="But it is not aligned on the left"/>
            <label class="col-xs-12">But I am aligned!</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<span class="col-xs-12">So texts are aligned, I would have expected the input control to be aligned instead of the text inside the input</span>
```

Comment: It seems that wrapping the input inside a div with col-xs-12 fixes the problem. But it overloads the form with markup which seems to me unnecessary. Is it the right way to do it (wrapping in DIV) ? Is it not OK to add a "col-" class on input ? Or is it a bug ? Check the new fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/7vRQr/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be the only one facing this issue...

Well, so for now I wrap every form control (input, textarea, select) inside a div with col-xs-12, and then it works OK.

So in my question, replacing this :

```
<input type="text" class="col-xs-12" placeholder="But it is not aligned on the left"/>
```

By this (encapsulating inside a div with col-xs-12) :

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" class="col-xs-12" placeholder="But it is not aligned on the left"/>
</div>
```

Fixes indentation issue. Please find the fully updated example here :
http://jsfiddle.net/7vRQr/5

Anyone with information about whether it is a bug or not (seems like one) or any other method to workaround is highly welcome. Because this solution does add a lot of extra HTML markups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<style>
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    text-align: left;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <h2>Following input should be aligned</h2>
            <div class="row">

      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="textbox">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exact same behaviour, don't understand why text-align would have anything to do with this. In your HTML you removed the col-xs-offset-1 that is why you may have different results. I integrated your suggestion in the fiddle, you will see no difference. http://jsfiddle.net/7vRQr/3/